# Why are prime numbers considered special

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

Why are prime numbers considered special because of the properties of having whole number factors of 1 and itself?
This seems rather arbitrary given the test is algorithmic and would compete with an infinite number of algorithmic tests resulting in a seemingly random selection pattern.
Hope i have expressed myself adequately

Comment: Define `special`. Even numbers are also *special* in their own way. So are multiples of $7$, or perfect squares, or triangular numbers etc.

Comment: If you think all algorithms are equally interesting, I don't know what to tell you...

Comment: I think one answer is that investigating the properties of prime numbers has led to a lot of beautiful math. It wasn't obvious originally that the study of prime numbers would turn out to be so fruitful.

Comment: I guess i was getting at the test for prime was rather arbitrary. Also the idea that one i NOT prime and 2 is the only even prime just sat uncomfortably with me but Oppa answered this well i think with prime factors. You cannot from my initial look make any whole number from factors of non-prime. at least the first ones so i guess the atoms of positive whole numbers sounds special indeed :-)

Answer (score 7):

Mostly because any non-prime integer can be factored in a unique product of prime numbers, that is: They are the *atoms* of the natural numbers. The same idea of primality can be expanded with a few tweaks$^{[1]}$ for polynomials, Gaussian integers, Hurwitz integers, etc.

In the case of polynomials, the factorization depends on the domain you're in $(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{Q},\dots)$ and the set of *prime* objects is different for each one of them. *Thinking* a little further, they are an interesting mathematical object which abstract the idea of mounting a certain object in which there is only one way to mount it, with certain rules, can be achieved.

An interesting and usually unusual theorem is the following:

> **Theorem** *(C. Cellitti,1914).* Every $2\times 2$ matrix with integral elements can be written as a product of powers of
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> {1}&{1}\\ 
> {0}&{1}
> \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad \begin{pmatrix}
> {1}&{0}\\ 
> {1}&{1}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> And matrices of the form
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> {a}&{0}\\ 
> {0}&{1}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Where $a\in \Bbb{Z}$.

This will show you that there are other sources of *factorization* in a way almost akin to the natural numbers. Take a look at **Weintraub's**: [*Factorization: Unique and Otherwise*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812418).

$[1]:$ See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) for prime elements and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) for irreducible elements. In some domains, they are different things.

Comment: Thanks, "They are the atoms of the natural numbers" I have seen this but it really works. Weird :-)

Comment: @Justin Did you see and understand the proof of the unique factorization?

Comment: Where do you find such interesting theorems?

Comment: @jm324354 Take a look at **Eves':** *Elementary Matrix Theory*. It is an interesting book because it has more theorems and ideas than proofs - but has a lot of references. I find this kind of book to be very useful if you want to make a quick map of the subject to explore the areas you find interesting later. Also, take a look of Eves' other books too, they are really worth reading.